# XSocket's Plug-in Framework not working: I cannot get an instance of IXSocketServerContainer

Tags: c#, websocket, xsockets.net

I have following code to start my server:

```
private static IXSocketServerContainer server = null;

public SocketServer()
{
    server = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>();
}
```

this worked fine for me under WinXP and Win7, with exactly the same set of dll and exe files, but now I deployed my system under WinServer 2008 and I get following error:

> clsSocketIntHandler|new , startin
>   servers|0|0||0||TypeInitializationException:  ; The type initializer
>   for 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable' threw an exception. ; The
>   module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131018)

Do you have any idea why could this be happening? What can be missing on my deployment machine? Can you please recommend me an alternative configuration to avoid this kind of dynamic loading?

My configuration now is as follows:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="XSockets.PluginCatalog" value="" />
   <add key="XSockets.PluginFilter" value="*.dll,*.exe" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: I have never seen that exception in XSockets, what version of XSockets are you running? Latest is 3.0.3

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253682/xsocket-net-without-plugin-framework/21268319#21268319

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answer this question only for completion and to help anyone that may face this problem. There are tow things you can do:
First: Upgrade to plug-in framework 1.3, (XSockets 3.0.3), this is mandatory
Second: try to limit the dll to load in case that you have a lot of libraries in the bin folder:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="XSockets.PluginCatalog" value="" />
  <add key="XSockets.PluginFilter" value="XSockets.*,your.dlls.*" />
  <!--
  <add key="SocketServer.StartServers.Location" value="ws://localhost:3232" />   
  -->
</appSettings>
```

Uffe, thanks for your help!!

Comment: This comment is also true for XSockets 4.2.0.0. It appears this isn't mandatory in version 5 anymore.