# XSocket.net without PlugIn-Framework

Tags: c#, websocket, xsockets.net

I cannot find in the documentation a way to start a XSocket server without using the PlugIn Framework.

I have a very easy library which contains its own controllers (located in the library itself) and which references XSockets.

I don't really need the PlugIn Framework and it is disturbing me because my library is located in a binaries folder with a number of other components that I don't manage. The PlugIn Framework is not working properly in such a complex environment and I'm quite sure it has to be possible to get an instance of the server singleton (new() is not working) without having to use:

```
server = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>();
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: You cant run XSocket without the plugin framework. The plugin framework is the very thing that makes the module architecture work. I´m pretty sure you can get it started if having all references and configurations in place.

Comment: @Rafa as Kim says you cant run XSockets without the plugin framework. I can help you out so that you get it up and running. If you do not want to paste details here you can send me an email (uffe at xsockets dot net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is this.
You have a non .net assembly in your bin folder. In XSocket plugin framwork version 1.1 there was a bug throwing an exception when trying to load an non .net assembly.

This issue is fixed in 1.3 (current version) and upgrading to XSockets 3.0.3 should take care of this issue.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! You're right, yesterday I upgraded to verison 1.3 of the plug-in framework and I was able to load the dll and even to limit the kind of dll that I load. Thanks for your great framework!!

Comment: here you can see what I did to make it run: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252220/xsockets-plug-in-framework-not-working-i-cannot-get-an-instance-of-ixsocketser/21277709#21277709